# Why a self-referencing sentinel in a red-black tree is simpler than having to check for NULL?

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement red-black tree data structure and came across [this](https://opensource.apple.com/source/sudo/sudo-46/src/redblack.c) example from Apple Open Source project. This is the code for creating a tree:

```
/*
 * Create a red black tree struct using the specified compare routine.
 * Allocates and returns the initialized (empty) tree.
 */
struct rbtree *
rbcreate(compar)
    int (*compar)__P((const void *, const void*));
{
    struct rbtree *tree;

    tree = (struct rbtree *) emalloc(sizeof(*tree));
    tree->compar = compar;

    /*
     * We use a self-referencing sentinel node called nil to simplify the
     * code by avoiding the need to check for NULL pointers.
     */
    tree->nil.left = tree->nil.right = tree->nil.parent = &tree->nil;
    tree->nil.color = black;
    tree->nil.data = NULL;

    /*
     * Similarly, the fake root node keeps us from having to worry
     * about splitting the root.
     */
    tree->root.left = tree->root.right = tree->root.parent = &tree->nil;
    tree->root.color = black;
    tree->root.data = NULL;

    return(tree);
}
```

I'm wondering what is the reasoning behind having the sentinel node instead having the children pointing to `NULL`. In any case we have to check as far as I understand.

Also I don't understand why we need fake root and how the root can even be split in theory?

Comment: If I remember right, a common trick is to put the "r-b-flag" into the least bit of one of the child pointers which is usually 0 (due to word alignment of addresses). This saves a byte or even a word for each node. In this case, comparison with 0 may have to mask this out - comparison with itself not. But, it's just speculation...

Comment: @Scheff: That may well be but the code quoted here would appear to store a separate color member.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even read the code - my fault...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you want to check one of the main properties of the RB tree, that there are no adjacent red nodes.

With NULL representation, it looks like this:

`node->color == black || (node->left == NULL || node->left->color == black) && (node->right == NULL || node->right->color == black)`

Sentinel representation allows to express it more concisely:

`node->color == black || node->left->color == black && node->right->color == black`

Same simplification applies to the actual checks in the tree operations.

Similar story with the fake root. It ensures that the tree is never empty, and thus eliminates a special case from the tree insertion routine. (No idea what they meant by spitting though.)

Comment: In addition to reducing special cases in a linked data structures using a sentinel as opposed to NULL allows the code to speculatively follow the chain, affording the optimizer more leeway in reordering.